# have other browsers implemented conditional comments?

Tags: css, multiple-browsers

IE allows you to do detect which version of IE is running based on their browsers comment conditions (I actually don't know if that is what they are called, someone can correct me if it is not).

```
<! --[if lt IE 7]> css code here.. <! [endif] -->
```

Does anyone know if other browsers have followed their example to determine what version of thier browser is being used?

```
<! --[if FF]> css code here.. <! [endif] -->
<! --[if O]> css code here.. <! [endif] -->
```

Comment: What are you truing to achieve that requires differentiation between browsers ?

Comment: I was wanting to use it for statistics. Nothing to try and hack functionality just pure data capture.

Comment: @John: Your web server can do this.

Comment: @reisio Can you point me in a good direction?

Comment: Web servers typically log all requests, including user agent string.  For some there is 3rd party software for visualizing it all, for example AWStats, etc. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWStats#Alternatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't need to do this with modern browsers (FF3.6, Chrome, IE9, Safari).  Also, if you target a hack at a browser that is still changing, you run the risk of the hack still working but the problem it solved being fixed, and then your fix breaks.

Hacks or conditional comments should only be aimed at old browsers (IE6 and IE7 are the main targets).

Answer (score 1):

No, conditional comments are only supported by Internet Explroer and the list of [available conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) is quite astounding.

Note that you can use conditional comments to **hide** things from IE browsers in general:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<b>This HTML is not seen by IE</b>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Ugly, ugly, though...

Comment: Many web developers are surprised to see that conditional comments exist. In many large companies, however, deployment of new browsers is glacial. I know a stockbroker working for a bank who is required to use IE6. Conditional comments make it possible for IT departments to support multiple versions of IE with all their quirks. A hack, yes, but not going away anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. Are you trying to serve up different CSS or a combo of CSS and JS/other?

Perhaps using the vendor prefixes like `-moz-`, `-webkit-` and `-o-` before CSS declarations might work for you in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Nope,

conditional comments are **IE only**.