# Valid "downlevel revealed" conditional comments

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

IE<9 does not understand `data:` URIs, so I'm outputting two different stylesheets: one with normal links to images for IE 8 and below, and one with base64-encoded inline images, for other browsers.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/themes/url.style.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/themes/b64.style.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Problem: In IE9, I'm seeing a stray `-->` output on the page. Because it's inside the `<head>` it appears at the very top of the page. How should I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I've got it. I did search for valid conditional comments, and found [an article telling me to do what I was already doing](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200511/valid_downlevelrevealed_conditional_comments/), but then by chance I came across a by-the-way remark in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4821893/209139) which showed me the correct way to do it:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<span>This is for IE 7 and below.</span>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<span>This is for all other browsers (IE 8, and browsers which don't do conditional comments).</span>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

See the difference: `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->` instead of `<!--[if gt IE 8]>-->`.